# Gigya Registraton using WebSDK

Tags: gigya

I am new to Gigya, I am integrating it on to my project.

Gigya Registration integrating using WebSDK,

on accounts.register() getting email verification popup, How to skip this step?

I have integrated magento plugin, from magento2 website am getting "A verification email with a link to verify your account has been sent to you."

Same thing I want it is using WebSDK.

Answer (score 2):

On Gigya you have [accounts.setPolicies](https://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/accounts.setPolicies+REST) where you set `verifyEmail` value to `false` or `allowUnverifiedLogin=true` in the `accountOptions` object. Both options will make this pop up disappear.

Also you can setup in the Gigya Console in the policies.